# How do I know what Interface is my public interface?

Tags: linux, network-interface, suse, route

I am setting up an application and it requires me to manually enter a public interface. When running `sudo route` it gives the following result:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.55.168.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.55.168.0     *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.123.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I can see that there are two interfaces but I am still unsure which one would be the public interface?

Comment: Could you give more information about the application, because I don't really understand what you said as public interface. If it means the interface to reach internet it would be eth0 because it is the default route.

Comment: The application being installed opens a new can of problems. It's OpenStack Neutron, but thanks, I never seen that before that the default Destination is set to eth0

Comment: In your case it is eth0, but not always. It could be wlan0 if you have a wireless interface, for example. The default Destination defines the gateway and the interface that can reach that gateway. When you send a packet to a IP address that is not in the route table then the packet is sent to the default Destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no formal definition of “public interface”. The most likely definition is that it's the one where packets go if they're going out to the Internet. That would be whichever interface has the default route. On Linux, you can query it programmatically from a shell with

```
route -n | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0" {print $8}'
```

Most Unix variants have a `route` command, its command line and output syntax may be a little different.

While the default route is the only viable candidate, it may or may not actually public. Many machines are behind a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) appliance, so they do not have a public interface at all. The NAT relays outgoing connections via its own public interface; incoming connections would reach the NAT appliance, and they wouldn't be routed to your machine unless the NAT is specifically configured to do so.

Answer (score 0):

External interfaces are in almost all cases the one having the default route, so that will do in most cases:

```
ip r | awk '/^default/ {print $5}'
```

If you however may have several default routes with different metric values, multiple routing tables and do source or policy based routing, you should know by yourself this here is not sufficient.

Comment: I actually tested this on a somewhat well known server provider, and it was `default dev venet0 scope link` which is not public. Even stranger, the next line contains the actual public IP address but it's also associated with `dev venet0` too.